# Стриминг видеофайла в реальном времени (node.js)

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных, видео

Есть ли способ стримить видеофаил с сервера на клиенты с привязкой к определенному моменту?
Т.е, грубо говоря, воспроизведение видео происходит на сервере, а клиентам отправялется текущий момент видео? Как прямая трансляция, но только не с камеры, а уже готового видеофайла?

Буду благодарен за указание готового nodejs модуля, или тыканье носом в технологию, да даже за корректные термины для гугла)
Всё что удалось найти больше заточено под простою отдачу видео или 
стрим с камер.

Спасибо!

Comment: Тут только перекодировать видео в реал тайме. Просто отдать видео файл с какого-то конкретного места нельзя (или очень сложно).

Comment: Так а как тогда происходит последовательная загрузка видео клиенту?
Т.е. ему отправяляются куски видео друг за другом. При этом он может ткнуть на таймлайне в конец видео и посмотреть сразу конец, не получая середины.
Но в это то и проблема - мне не нужно что бы клиент мог пользоваться таймлайном или смотреть дальше того момента, который сейчас должен быть воспроизведен.

Comment: При перемотке считываются заголовки видео файла вначале (иногда и в конце). Так же есть такое понятие как ключевые кадры. Например, что бы получить кадр с номером 12345, нужно отдать клиенту все кадры начиная с 12300, потому что они зависят от него. Иначе видео плеер не сможет ничего показать. Вы хотите это всё программировать вручную?)

Comment: я совсем не против)
но у меня пробел в теоретической части, куча новых терминов, которые выводят не на те технологии. WebRTC не подхожит, HLS вроде режет видео на части, но тоже заточен под полную отдачу контента до конца..
Пока теряюсь, не понимаю что гуглить. Всё в конечном итоге упирается в твичи и ютубы. Понять бы подкапотную часть =\

Comment: На твиче всё просто, там видео режется кусками по 15 или 30 сек, не помню точно, и они отдаются в виде .ts файлов. Каждый кусок это полноценный видео файл с заголовками, и его можно открыть в видеоплеере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через WebRTC, можно через MPEG-DASH и т.д. В любом случае вам нужен отдельный нативный бэк / сервер, который отдаёт или перекодирует видео. На nodejs такие задачи лучше не пихать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я использовал https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server/ + ffmpeg и всё заработало как надо